# Android 4.4 breaks jquery on(touchstart/touchmove/touchend)?

Tags: android, jquery

I built a doodle app in html + Cordova/Phonegap. I use jquery(elem).on(touchstart/-move/-end) to listen to touchevents. But this seems to be broken in Android 4.4; it only fires touchstart.

Any tips?

EDIT: here's the code

```
$("#canvas_doodle").on("touchstart", function(e){ doo.touchBegin(e); });
$("#canvas_doodle").on("touchmove",  function(e){ doo.touchMove(e); });
$("#canvas_doodle").on("touchend",  function(e){ doo.touchEnd(e); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Steve P, but I figured it out (forgot to answer the question).

Somehow I forgot to call e.preventDefault() in touchBegin and touchMove, which caused touchEnd to never fire when dragging.

Comment: But it's still a problem, if I call `e.preventDefault()` in every  `touchstart`, it will stop the web page's normal behavior.

Comment: @Aloong: that's why I attach the listener to the canvas and not the entire document :)

Comment: Its been nearly 2 years, i am just wondering did you managed to get the touchend to work when you add the e.preventDefault() to the touchmove? As below? Because i couldnt get it working even when i add e.preventDefault() to the touchmove.    $("#record").on('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault();})

Comment: @John You have to call preventDefault in touchstart. Not sure if it also needs to be called in touchmove

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yer it works when i take out the other function's trigger within that touchstart, but when i add in back in, weirdly it stops working haha i gotta figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("touchstart", '#canvas_doodle', function(e){ doo.touchBegin(e); });
```

...